# Does Convert.ChangeType() just return a differently typed reference to the passed value?

Tags: c#, object, polymorphism

The Microsoft docs say that Convert.ChangeType returns

> An object whose type is conversionType and whose value is equivalent to value.

I'm not sure what that means. Here's my scenario.

```cs
ParentType parent = new ChildType();

Type type = parent.GetType();

parent.SomeMemberProperty = 1;

dynamic child = Convert.ChangeType(parent, type);

child.SomeMemberProperty = 2;
```

What then is the result of `parent.SomeMemberProperty`?

EDIT: Please ignore the simplicity/stupidity of the above scenario. It's just meant to demonstrate the confusion I have and I'd never actually write that code.

Comment: Can't you just run the code and see?

Comment: What confusion do you have? `Convert.ChangeType` will cast `parent` from type `ChildType` (which is the type the `parent` object has because it was instantiated that way) to `ChildType` (the value of the variable `type` which is the runtime type of `parent` which is what I said before) – so not doing anything at all. Leaving the `dynamic` aside (which needlessly complicates this) `child` and `parent` are the same object.

Comment: @Sweeper that's what I ended up doing! :)

Comment: @ckuri the purpose of the dynamic and indeed using Convert.ChangeType() in the first place was because I don't know the actual Type at compile time. And per the Edit, I'd never actually write code like in the example. It's a contrived situation to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType()` does not copy the parent. It merely provides a differently typed reference to it, so any mutations to child will affect the parent object as well.